# CAST error on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have created a little apps in c# with WPF 4.0 and a datagrid.
My datagrid is bound to somes data members of a "TableCompte" Object

I would like to make some test after a line entered, so, i use the RowEditEnding event.

Here is my code

```
private void dataGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    TableCompte Compte = e.Row.DataContext as TableCompte;

    if (Compte  != null)
    {
       // Verifs
    }
}
```

My problem is my object "**Compte**" is null.

Nevertheless, my "**DataContext**" Value is good ! So it's a cast error, but where is my error?

Here is my XAML declaration :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" Name="dataGrid1" AreRowDetailsFrozen="false" Margin="31,227,28,82" RowEditEnding="dataGrid1_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte d'origine" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteOrigine, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 1" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux1, Mode=TwoWay ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 1" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux1, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 2" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 2" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux2, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Compte Taux 3" Binding="{Binding Path=m_CompteTaux3, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="134" Header="Taux 3" Binding="{Binding Path=m_Taux3, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Debugger? Check `e.Row.DataContext`?

Comment: What is the ItemsSource of dataGrid1? Is it a DataTable ?

Comment: e.row.dataContext is correct ! That's why i know it's a Cast Error.

Comment: I don't have set an itemsSource on my DataGrid ( you can saw it on my XAML code)

Comment: Check the type of `DataContext`. Is it actually of type `TableCompte`?

Comment: Yes, it's TableCompte type :)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni, it can't be, or the cast would succeed... Try using Item instead of DataContext

Answer (score 1):

`e.Row.DataContext` contains the item source for the row, NOT the data source for the DataGrid.

So it will be what ever `m_CompteOrigine`, `m_CompteTaux1`, `m_CompteTaux2`, etc. contains.
Do they all have the same Type or Interface?

You should cast to the common type/interface of the item source.

Assuming:

```
Compte m_CompteOrigine;
Compte m_CompteTaux1;
```

Then do:

```
private void dataGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
Compte Compte = e.Row.DataContext as Compte;

if (Compte  != null)
{
   // Verifs
}
}
```

If you are still having a problem.  Try debugging and setting a break point at the assignment statement.  Then use the debugger to examine `e.Row.DataContext`; it will show you its Type.

Good luck